# AWS SageMaker Invoke Endpoint Error: could not convert string "xxxxx" to float

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have an endpoint configured in AWS SageMaker. I am attempting to invoke the endpoint and pass a test datapoint to obtain the predictions. However, I am running into some datatype conversion issue. My model is trained on numeric and categorical variables.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                       
                       'Year': 2000,
                       'Val': 85,
                       'Score': 60,
                       'Area': 'x1isz2',
                       'Rate': 0.05312,

                }, index=[0])

point_X = np.expand_dims(df.to_numpy(), axis=0)

np.savetxt("test_point.csv", point_X[0][0], delimiter=",", fmt='%s')

file_name = ("test_point.csv")
```

Either do this:

```
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    payload = f.read().strip()
```

or try this:

```
payload = ','.join([str(item) for item in point_X[0][0]])
print(payload)

response = runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name, ContentType="text/csv", Body=payload
)


2000, 85, 60, x1isz2, 0.05312


169.254.178.2 - - [23/Nov/2021:00:12:55 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"
169.254.178.2 - - [23/Nov/2021:00:13:00 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"
169.254.178.2 - - [23/Nov/2021:00:13:05 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"
169.254.178.2 - - [23/Nov/2021:00:13:10 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"
169.254.178.2 - - [23/Nov/2021:00:13:15 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "AHC/2.0"
[2021-11-23:00:13:15:INFO] Determined delimiter of CSV input is ','
[2021-11-23:00:13:15:ERROR] Loading csv data failed with Exception, please ensure data is in csv format:
 <class 'ValueError'>
 could not convert string to float: 'Year'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve_utils.py", line 47, in parse_content_data
    dtest = encoder.csv_to_dmatrix(decoded_payload, dtype=np.float)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/encoder.py", line 50, in csv_to_dmatrix
    np_payload = np.array(list(map(lambda x: _clean_csv_string(x, delimiter), string_like.split('\n')))).astype(dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Year'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve.py", line 155, in invocations
    dtest, content_type = serve_utils.parse_content_data(payload, flask.request.content_type)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/serve_utils.py", line 50, in parse_content_data
    "please ensure data is in csv format:\n
```

Comment: please provide your full source. are you using the sklearn estimator image?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I added the full error traceback.

Comment: i think the problem is you have the column names in the first row of your input file

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan columns names are removed. I am passing a numpy array that looks like this: `2000, 85, 60, x1isz2, 0.05312`.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that the header is passed to the endpoint during invocation , can you remove the header and pass only the row values for invocation